# Use a function with arguments in angular expression

Tags: angularjs, expression, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to dynamically set a CSS value from inside `ng-repeat` so I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
style="right:{{ getProgressPercentage(value) }}"
```

The `value` is part of the `ng-repeat`: `ng-repeat="(title, value) in statistics.options"` and the function is defined in `$rootScope`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you include code examples of `getProgressPercentage(value)`?

Comment: dont define functions in $rootscope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-style`:

```
<elem ng-style="getProgressPercentage(value)"></elem>
```

And the JS:

```
$scope.getProgressPercentage = function(val) {
    //do stuff
    return { left: "45%" }; //or whatever
}
```